# Cucumber > watir-webdriver > email spec: how to test?

Tags: email, cucumber, watir-webdriver, specifications

So, can you please whrite me an example, how I use email spec in cucumber with watir-webdriver.

I can not it find hier: https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec

and hier: https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec/wiki/Use-Cucumber-to-Test-Email

It doesn't works at me... :(

```
Then /^I should receive an email with a link to a confirmation page$/ do
  unread_emails_for(current_email_address).size.should == 1  
  open_last_email_for(last_email_address)
  current_email.should have_subject(/ALPHAJUMP: Bitte bestätigen Sie Ihre Registrierung./)
  current_email.should have_body_text('Herzlich willkommen')
  click_email_link_matching /Jetzt freischalten/
  page.should have_content("Wir begrüßen Sie auf ALPHAJUMP!")
end
```

Error message: expected: 1
               got: 0 (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)

Comment: You did not say what the problem is. "Does not work" is not enough data.

Comment: Error: uninitialized constant Delayed::Job (NameError)

But I don't use Delayed_job. Should I it using?

Comment: Please provide the code that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message says you did not require [delayed_job](https://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job) gem. This could fix the problem:

```
require 'delayed_job'
```

Since that is not the title of the question, I guess you still have not clue how to test e-mail with Cucumber, but I guess that should be another question.